# Triple Integrals in spherical coordinates bound by E

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, riemann-integration

I am trying to solve the triple integral xyz dxdydz where E is the surface bounded by E = {(x,y,z) ∈ R^3 : 4<= x^2+y^2+z^2<=9, x<=0, z<=0}. I am unsure what E actually means and what equations you are integrating between.If someone could help me understand this then I should be able to compute the final answer.

Comment: First of all, use MathJAX. You are not a new contributor anymore. If you were having trouble with the curly braces the escape character would make it work (like this \{ ). $E$ describes a set of points that is between two shapes but also has some restriction on $x$ and $z$. Could you describe those?

Comment: $E$ is not "the surface bounded by" anything, it's a solid consisting of all points $(x,y,z)$ whose coordinates satisfy the inequalities you have written.

Comment: As for the computation of the integral, the shape of $E$ makes it natural to change to spherical coordinates (although this is not the only option).

Answer (score 0):

This is an integral over $xyz$ over the spherical shell bound by the spheres of radii 2 and 3,
in the quadrant $x\le 0$, $z\le 0$.
Because the integrand contains the factor $y$ and for any $x$ and $z$ both $y$ are included,
these contributions cancel, and the integral is zero.